# How to make Ganglia graphs work with Flume

Tags: flume

I am monitoring a multi agent flume setup with gangaila. I am able to produce metrics which I can view as JSON data on the browser. Can anyone suggest me how to view these metrics in graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting the flume agent provide following java options:

```
-Dflume.monitoring.type=ganglia
-Dflume.monitoring.hosts=<host:port of ganglia monitor daemon>
```

Depending on the flume installation these can be set in flume-env.sh (in mine the file is in /etc/flume/conf).

You won't be able to run http and ganglia monitoring at the same time.

Comment: What changes are needed to ganglia configuration?